# Where to find information about WiFi connectivity of the device?

Tags: shell, system, kernel, command-line

is there a way I can find information about my device's connectivity to WiFi network? I need information like: what network I'm connected too, what is the mac address of the router, how long have I been connected, when was the initial connection.
I tried looking in `proc/net`, but I didn't find any useful information there? Is there any other place I can look in?

Answer (score 3):

You can use various Wifi/network analysis apps from Play Store to get some of the information you're looking for. I suggest [IP Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ddm.iptools). In its default screen/view, you would get to see following information *et al*:

- SSID
- Internal IP
- Your Android device's MAC address
- Gateway
- DNS
- Frequency
- BSSID (your router's MAC address)
- Lease duration

If you need more information, you'd need to setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) and issue this command:

```
adb shell dumpsys wifi
```

It would throw incredible amount of information, most of it incomprehensible for an end-user. However, it would show even such information not available to apps, such as, when was the device last connected or disconnected from a Wi-Fi.

In my Android 8.1.0 (OnePlus 6), I get to see this information *et al*:

```
WifiMetrics:
mConnectionEvents:

startTime=12-23 21:36:05.762, SSID="Connected, no internet", BSSID=ROUTER'S_MAC_ADDRESS, durationMillis=1530, roamType=ROAM_UNRELATED, connectionResult=
1, level2FailureCode=NONE, connectivityLevelFailureCode=NONE, signalStrength=-34, wifiState=WIFI_DISCONNECTED, screenOn=true. mRouterFingerprint: mCo
nnectionEvent.roamType=0, mChannelInfo=2412, mDtim=0, mAuthentication=2, mHidden=false, mRouterTechnology=4, mSupportsIpv6=false

startTime=12-23 22:32:56.874, SSID="Connected, no internet", BSSID=ROUTER'S_MAC_ADDRESS, durationMillis=1541, roamType=ROAM_UNRELATED, connectionResult=
1, level2FailureCode=NONE, connectivityLevelFailureCode=NONE, signalStrength=-28, wifiState=WIFI_DISCONNECTED, screenOn=true. mRouterFingerprint: mCo
nnectionEvent.roamType=0, mChannelInfo=2412, mDtim=0, mAuthentication=2, mHidden=false, mRouterTechnology=4, mSupportsIpv6=false

startTime=12-23 22:36:49.886, SSID="Connected, no internet", BSSID=ROUTER'S_MAC_ADDRESS, durationMillis=1542, roamType=ROAM_UNRELATED, connectionResult=
1, level2FailureCode=NONE, connectivityLevelFailureCode=NONE, signalStrength=-28, wifiState=WIFI_DISCONNECTED, screenOn=true. mRouterFingerprint: mCo
nnectionEvent.roamType=0, mChannelInfo=2412, mDtim=0, mAuthentication=2, mHidden=false, mRouterTechnology=4, mSupportsIpv6=false
```

The aforesaid information tells me the last three times (because I restarted my device earlier, so not much of earlier information available) my device connected to a Wi-Fi.

If you look into the log entries under *Dump of WifiConnectivityManager* you would get to know more info on when the device was disconnected and then connected.

Moreover, the dump output also has all the information I listed above for IP Tools app. It is only a matter of filtering the important information out of that dump.

Comment: Thanks for the reply? Is it possible running dumpsys wifi, using Java RunTime, I want to process that information and show connection time to the user.

Comment: I don't know about that. Sorry!